# Why two Rakshasa idols are kept near the main idol of Govindaraja Temple, Tirupati?

Tags: temple, rakshasa, tirupati

I was listening to Chaganti Koteswara Rao's speeches about the Govindaraja Temple, Tirupati. He said that there 2 Rakshasas are kept near main idol.

Why 2 Rakshasas are kept near the main idol of Govindaraja Temple, Tirupati?

Comment: Can you add Video link if possible?